# Does Influx 0.9 retention policy remove data?

Tags: influxdb

I'm running InfluxDB 0.9.6.1 and have retention policy 'ten_weeks' just applied, see below:

```
> show retention policies on firewalls
name            duration        replicaN        default
default         0               1               true
ten_weeks       1680h0m0s       1               false
```

Should I expect data older than 10 weeks to be removed at the moment I applied this retention policy ? I don't think it happened based on free disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any data that is in the `ten_weeks` that is more than ten weeks old should be dropped. Retention policy enforcement happens every 15 minutes.

If data is not being dropped, I'd assume that it had been written to a different retention policy.

A common misconception is that a retention policy is a policy that applies to data. A retention policy is a container for data, and that data expires according to the `duration` of the retention policy.